# Transparent background EditText over ImageView won't display cursor

Tags: java, android, android-layout, view, android-edittext

So, I want the user to be able to type over an image that I set to an Image View. The image is set and works. When the user clicks the image, an Edit Text box shows up where they clicked. But the white background of the Edit Text blocks the image in the background. So, I set the Edit Text background to transparent:

```
    editTextOne.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
```

This works with making the Edit Text background transparent. However, now the cursor also doesn't display, unless, the begin typing.

So, what I'm asking is if there is anyway to make the EditText background transparent but still have the cursor show and blink? Any help will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Code:

```
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent event){
            if (type == true){
                touchX = (int) event.getX();
                touchY = (int) event.getY();
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) editTextOne.getLayoutParams();
                params.leftMargin = touchX;
                params.topMargin = touchY;
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_TOP);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
                editTextOne.setLayoutParams(params);
                editTextOne.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                editTextOne.bringToFront();
                editTextOne.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
                editTextOne.requestFocus();
                editTextOne.setCursorVisible(true);
            }//end of if statement
            return true;
        }//end of onTouch
```

XML:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/relative" >

<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/load"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="C"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/camera"
    android:onClick="camera"/>

<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/view"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/load"
    android:text="L"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:onClick="load"/>

<Button
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="v"
    android:id="@+id/view"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:onClick="view"/>

<Button 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/camera"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:text="T"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:onClick="text"/>

<TextView 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:id="@+id/textone"/>

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    android:inputType="textAutoCorrect"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:id="@+id/edittextone"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:id="@+id/picture"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT: I'm not to sure why the cursor wouldn't display right away but I found that the cursor was visible once the space bar was pressed. So, in order to solve my problem I used:

```
     editTextOne.setText(" ");
```

This places a space as the initial text, and therefore, displays the cursor. I hope that this may help someone else stuck with a similar problem.

Comment: did you find any other solution apart from settext(" ").Iam having the same problem it maybe helpfull for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried manually setting the focus to the text view? After you show the view, you can try calling [requestFocus()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#requestFocus%28%29)?

Also, you can attempt to explicitly set the cursor to visible through the [setCursorVisible](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCursorVisible%28boolean%29) method.

Comment: I tried to use requestFocus() like this: editTextOne.requestFocus(), yet, still no luck. Also, I realized I made a mistake with the description, even as I type the letters the cursor still won't show.

Comment: Also, I have tried using editTextOne.setCursorVisible(true); like you have said. Still no luck for some reason. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Sorry, I didn`t become clear - does your text show up when you type, even though the cursor itself is hidden?

Comment: There could be many reasons for the cursor to disappear, could you provide more information on your layouts?
Two popular solution are to set your view to singleline if it is too narrow or to provide an inputType.

Comment: Hmm, I know that inflating a layout can clear its properties, but not parameters as far as I know. Could you try setting singleLine and touchInput on runtime again, just in case? Could you also try giving the layout a fixed width instead of wrap, does the view resize right now as you type inside of it?

Comment: I managed to solve my problem. For some reason the cursor was only displaying once the space bar was hit. So, I used setText(" ") to initially set the text as a space. This displays the cursor right away. Thanks for all your help, though, I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

you can change editext property **android:background="@null"** in xml file ,not set in code file ,it is work for me.i hope it use full fore you.

Answer (score 1):

First i want to make sure that you want to change your cursor color . is it ?

For that :

- change your minimum api (if api < 3.2 ).
- set as **android api 3.2 or more.**
- you will get properties in EditText , set as **android:textCursorDrawable="@null"**
- change your text:color that will also set a color of cursor same as
  text color.

This will **only help you if your minimum api level is 3.2 else not.**

Comment: No, unfortunately, my problem doesn't have to do with the cursor color. No matter what color the background is, the cursor won't display.